# Java Thread catching all Exceptions?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging, thread-safety

When I run my code in debug mode in Eclipse, I'm able to find where the code breaks down, but an exception is not being shown on the council. In debug mode, I notice that after an exception is thrown, it seems to be swallowed up by the thread it's running on, and the program keeps going (or at least, keeps running. The program itself becomes unusable). Is there any way to get errors thrown in threads to be more visible?

I apologies if I've misinterpreted the path the debugger took through the code when it reached the exception. It *seems* to me that it is being caught by the thread. Regardless, whenever I have threaded code, I have a hard time finding out what the error was.

Comment: Could always write out to a log file. Debugging multithreaded applications can be difficult with most IDEs.

Comment: While the question is about error visibility, I sometimes need to make threads robust and restart on demand. I will create a `Runnable` where the `run()` method is an infinite loop containing a try/catch that logs the exception and keeps going (and of course breaking the loop for `InterruptedException`). And of course I submit this to an `Executor` instead of managing threads the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Eclipse debugger, you can configure a breakpoint to break whenever some specified `Exception` is thrown.

To set this up:

On the debugger's **Breakpoints** tab, press the **J!** button. This will enable you to *Add Java Exception breakpoint*. You can also choose to suspend the JVM or thread that throws the Exception.

Just prior to your specified `Exception` being thrown, the debugger will **suspend the thread or the JVM (all threads)** depending on your choice. At this point, you can begin to diagnose the problem. It's not foolproof, but it will give you an excellent starting point to debugging your issue.

If you don't know what Exception is thrown, you can choose `java.lang.Exception`. This will pause for any `Exception` thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to [register an UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) with the thread, in which you can do the required logging.